# Function that changes structure

Tags: javascript

I need some advice for this task.

We've got this structure:

```
const scenes = {
  'Node1': {
    'scene1': [
      {
        nodeKey: 'cccc',
        category: 'user',
      },
      {
        nodeKey: 'eeee',
        category: 'interface',
      },
    ]
  },
}
```

I need to make this:

```
let result = {
  'Node1': {
    'scene1': {
      'cccc': {
        nodeKey: 'cccc',
        category: 'user',
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I use the reduce function to make it work. But I think it can be done more efficiently and maybe more readable?

```
function makeNewStructure(scenes) {
  return Object.keys(scenes).reduce((prevNode, currentNode) => {
    return {
      ...prevNode, 
      [currentNode]: Object.keys(scenes[currentNode]).reduce((prevScene, currentScene) => {
      return {
        ...prevScene, 
        [currentScene]: scenes[currentNode][currentScene].reduce((previous, current) => {
          return {
            ...previous,
            [current.nodeKey]: current
          }
        },{})
      }
      }, {})
    }
  }, {})
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. Please provide a better specification of what the transformation is, because the example is unclear. What happens to `'eeee'`, and why? See [ask].

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure you can get it much "smarter" but I believe this is clearer:

```
function forEach(target, fn) {
    var keys = Object.keys(target);
    var key;
    var i = -1;
    while (++i < keys.length) {
        key = keys[i];
        fn(target[key], key);
    }
}
function transform(target, fn, accumulator) {
    if (accumulator === undefined) {
        accumulator = Object.create(target);
    }
    forEach(target, function (value, key) {
        return fn(accumulator, value, key);
    });
    return accumulator;
}
function makeNewStructure(scenes) {
    var result = [];
    return transform(scenes, function (acc, value, key) {
        acc[key] = {};
        return transform(value, function (acc, value, key) {
            acc[key] = {};
            value.forEach(function (node) {
                acc[key][node.nodeKey] = node;
            });
        }, acc[key]);
    }, result);
}

makeNewStructure(scenes);
```

The 2 utility functions I have taken from my own library: [goodcore](https://github.com/AllNamesRTaken/GoodCore). But I have written them here so that you dont have to use it if you dont want to.